# How to set class name in selenium?

Tags: selenium

```
<div id=“idname” class=“class”></div>
<div id=“idname” class=“class”></div>
.
.
.
<div id=“idname” class=“class”></div>
<div id=“idname” class=“class test”></div>
<div id=“idname” class=“class”></div>
```

I have this code. There are countless divs, and only one of them has class ="class test".

How to set class name in selenium?

Comment: What do you mean by "How to set class name in selenium"? Selenium should not **set** class name of a web element. It can **select** web element based on a class name or any other attribute

Comment: @Prophet: Selenium can add/modify HTML attributes through JS injection. However psj question is not really clear. psj: did you mean to ask How to select class `class test` in selenium?

Comment: @cruisepandey I know. This is what and why I'm trying to ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to select an element with class `class test` you can do it with XPath

`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class test']")`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are asking how to **select** web element based on `class test` class value - it can be done with XPath like this:

```
//div[@class='class test']
```

or CSS Selector like this

```
div.class.test
```